How can I upgrade from Centos Stream 8 to 9, now that 8 is EOL?
When I google for this, the walkthroughs I find tend to start with
dnf install dnf-plugin-system-upgrade

Unfortunately, now that CS8 is EOL, that returns
CentOS Stream 8 - AppStream                                                                                                                                   
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: No URLs in mirrorlist

So now that CS8 iS EOL, what's the "best" way to attempt to update to 9?

Clean install, restore data from backup.
If you were considering switching distros, this would be an opportunity to do so.
